# Codeblocks doesn't support glfw3?

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks, glfw

I'm learning opengl and wanted to use Codeblocks IDE because visual studio seems too laggy and slow. After starting a console application project i've tried to link GLFW3 library to make this code run:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

I use GNU GCC 32-bit Compiler from MinGW(one that comes with codeblocks installation). I'm pretty certain that i've done everything correctly, i've read through like every article that i was able to find explaining how to setup codeblocks for opengl. I've linked libglfw3.a and libglfw3dll.a and set up correct search directories for compiler and linker but i always get this undefined reference error no matter what:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in glfw_again_test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib" -o bin\Debug\glfw_again_test.exe obj\Debug\main.o   "C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3.a" "C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libglfw3dll.a" "C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libopengl32.a"
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `main':
C:/dev/OpenGL/CodeBlocks/glfw_again_test/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
C:/dev/OpenGL/CodeBlocks/glfw_again_test/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

I have no idea what else i could try to fix this problem.

Comment: Sorry, already found the answer for now. Apparently i was mistaken and thought that i use 32-bit MinGW compiler but seems like i accidentally installed 64-bit one with codeblocks. After switching to mingw gcc 32-bit compiler and rebuilding(simple build will lead to an error) my project i finally got it to work(not exactly this code snippet but another sample one). Hope this will help anyone who faced the same problem.

Comment: Please create an answer post. If it is according to [answer] you can probably harvest some reward for your effort.

Comment: And if you [edit] the question according to [ask], i.e. so that it has all the info needed so that somebody else could also have answered it, then - well - twice.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently i was mistaken and thought that i use 32-bit MinGW compiler but seems like i accidentally installed 64-bit one with codeblocks. After switching to mingw gcc 32-bit compiler and rebuilding(simple build will lead to an error) my project i finally got it to work(not exactly this code snippet but another sample one).